# Running php pthreads

Tags: php, pthreads

I have a php installation on ubuntu linux that works just fine but i now need to use the pool class.

I have the ordinary php and apache setup running on port 80. I want to use the pool class to create 100 workers to process many many rows of mysql data.

Should i run the pool class based program using cli like `php -f file.php` or what method should i use.

Is the ordinary php serving content to end users on port 80 different from the one at php cli?.

Will running the pool class based program eat into the ordinary php resources if i am running the pool program from cli?

In the requirements

> pthreads requires a build of PHP with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety)
>   enabled ( --enable-maintainer-zts or --enable-zts on Windows )

Comment: You'll need to recompile your PHP installation to use ZTS. As an alternative you can use normal PHP CLI processes and then use ZMQ for messaging between processes.

Comment: Supposing i have installed the ordinary php and the php cli side by side and it so happens that a cli program is using more resources than it should, will that affect my ordinary php installation that i use to server web pages?.

Comment: Yes of course. But pthreads will do the same. CPU cycles, RAM, HDD bandwidth and other I/O can not come from nowhere. May be you should offload this to another server and then messaging solution like ZMQ is your best option.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea.I will offload pthreads to another server.

Comment: You don't need pthreads for this though (no recompiling of PHP required). You can manage normal CLI processes with supervisord or just start them from `/etc/rc.local`(not recommended).

Comment: I am running away from supervisord. I had the option of using beanstalkd but pthreads looks like this new toy i can control by myself.Its never very clear how multiple workers are being created in beanstalkd and the documentation isnt that clear on that.

Comment: Do not use more workers than you have CPU cores.  Or, if you do, cautiously increase the number until you have saturated some resource (cpu / IO / network / etc), then stop increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the official PHP pthreads page:

> Warning
>   The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server environment. Threading in PHP should therefore remain to CLI-based applications only.

So, it's a good idea(It is the ONLY reasonable way) to use your pthreaded script through CLI.
also see [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/parallel-programming-pthreads-php-fundamentals/#whennottousepthreads)

I can't understand what exactly you mean with "Is the ordinary php serving content to end users on port 80 different from the one at php cli?" - on port 80 your apache server run the script and serve the output to end users through HTTP/S. In CLI output can be the same for default STDOUT, but there is only you like a end user.

A pool with 100 workers will "eat" a lot of system resources.